# Not getting update in worklight 6.3 when connected to local with existing 6.0.2 code migrating to Worklight 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am migrating my existing project from worklight 6.0.2 to 6.3 with existing environment(No environment change) but i am not able to update the changes connecting to my localhost in iOS(both iPhone and iPad) same is working fine in Android.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?  Any configuration files that changed in the upgrade?  We need more details to help you out.

Comment: Mention the migration error you are getting, or any other error. Right now you are only saying "I've got an error". Provide more information.

Comment: @satish raizada, Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in fact referring to Direct Update when you say "unable to update"?

One suggestion to try is to delete the iphone\native folder (assuming you do not have any custom native code, otherwise back it up and put it back in later), and then re-build the application. Then, deploy to device and see that Direct Update now works.